# "call ready" response to AT COMMANDS and nothing written to the sim808

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command

I'm using "mega 2650 pro" 5 volt voltage pin output as a power to "sim808 bk-808-v3.1" vcc.

When I tried commands, "call ready" response appear and AT+CSCS="GSM" not written as you can see in the following picture

[image]

the following is the code I uploaded to arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    
  if (Serial.available())
  { 
    while(Serial.available())
    {
      mySerial.write(Serial.read());
    }
    mySerial.println();
  }
}
```

so what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: You mean you are powering the GPS/GSM module from the Vcc output power on the ATMega board, right? After reading your question I understood you were using an I/O pin as a power source!

Comment: yes, because I still test my project. Is there any way to solve the problem? @MarcosG.

Comment: it is quite strange. Have you tried `AT+CSCS=? ` to see if GSM is in the list of supported charsets?

Comment: yes, it's in the list.

the problem maybe that the current is not enough, so the sim808 not connected to the network. @MarcosG.

Comment: That is a possibility, but it would be very easy to check, just use another power supply or provide power to the module from somewhere else.

Comment: @MarcosG. thanks, i will try